# Image all zeros after encoding and decoding it

Tags: image, go

While I was writing test I ran into this strange behaviour that, when given a random image to `png.Encode`, then decoding the given byte array again with `png.Decode` it is all zeros (Despite the fact that is a `image.NRGBA` image - that should be fixed for comparison)

I created a playground for my code here: https://play.golang.org/p/S6XJLVMOLyQ

But for completeness by example code is here:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "reflect"
    "image/color"
    "bytes"
    "image/png"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {

    width := 5
    height := 5
    
    upLeft := image.Point{0, 0}
    lowRight := image.Point{width, height}

    inImage := image.NewRGBA(image.Rectangle{upLeft, lowRight})
    
    for x := 0; x < width; x++ {
        for y := 0; y < height; y++ {

            // Colors are defined by Red, Green, Blue, Alpha uint8 values.
            randomColor := color.RGBA{
                uint8(rand.Intn(255)),
                uint8(rand.Intn(255)),
                uint8(rand.Intn(255)),
                0x00}
            inImage.Set(x, y, randomColor)
        }
    }
    
    out := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err := png.Encode(out, inImage)
    
    if err != nil {
        panic("Something went wrong")
    }
    
    reader := bytes.NewReader(out.Bytes())
    outImage, err := png.Decode(reader)
    
    areEqual := reflect.DeepEqual(inImage, outImage)
        
    // Might have to convert it to image.RGBA here - but still all bytes are zero now
    
    fmt.Printf("Are Equal: %s\n\n\texp: %#v\n\n\tgot: %#v\033[39m\n\n", areEqual, inImage, outImage)
}
```

Which returns:

```
Are Equal: %!s(bool=false)

exp: &image.RGBA{Pix:[]uint8{0x56, 0x84, 0x7a, 0x0, 0xef, 0x60, 0x9b, 0x0, 0x10, 0x8a, 0x4d, 0x0, 0xfc, 0x76, 0x5e, 0x0, 0x65, 0x5a, 0xa5, 0x0, 0xfe, 0x97, 0x99, 0x0, 0xa7, 0x83, 0x32, 0x0, 0x92, 0xae, 0xb, 0x0, 0xd6, 0x7b, 0xde, 0x0, 0xab, 0x1, 0x17, 0x0, 0x73, 0x9b, 0x3d, 0x0, 0x42, 0x8f, 0x85, 0x0, 0x48, 0xd3, 0x2d, 0x0, 0x3d, 0x54, 0x81, 0x0, 0xce, 0x6b, 0xf8, 0x0, 0x96, 0x77, 0x97, 0x0, 0xed, 0x25, 0x34, 0x0, 0x9c, 0x67, 0xdc, 0x0, 0xcd, 0xfa, 0x53, 0x0, 0xb0, 0x85, 0x8d, 0x0, 0x2a, 0x3b, 0x58, 0x0, 0xd0, 0xb4, 0x96, 0x0, 0x9a, 0x30, 0x2b, 0x0, 0x12, 0x67, 0xaa, 0x0, 0x89, 0x53, 0xde, 0x0}, Stride:20, Rect:image.Rectangle{Min:image.Point{X:0, Y:0}, Max:image.Point{X:5, Y:5}}}

got: &image.NRGBA{Pix:[]uint8{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, Stride:20, Rect:image.Rectangle{Min:image.Point{X:0, Y:0}, Max:image.Point{X:5, Y:5}}}[39m
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you draw completely transparent pixels (alpha=0), so when encoding it, the [`png`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/png/) package will "optimize" the image and encode a completely black image (which is the same).

Change the alpha component to `255` being completely opaque:

```
randomColor := color.RGBA{
    uint8(rand.Intn(255)),
    uint8(rand.Intn(255)),
    uint8(rand.Intn(255)),
    255} // MAX ALPHA
```

With this simple change output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/URZnwnILHTS)):

```
Are Equal: true

    exp: &image.RGBA{Pix:[]uint8{0x56, 0x84, 0x7a, 0xff, 0xef, 0x60, 0x9b, 0xff, 0x10, 0x8a, 0x4d, 0xff, 0xfc, 0x76, 0x5e, 0xff, 0x65, 0x5a, 0xa5, 0xff, 0xfe, 0x97, 0x99, 0xff, 0xa7, 0x83, 0x32, 0xff, 0x92, 0xae, 0xb, 0xff, 0xd6, 0x7b, 0xde, 0xff, 0xab, 0x1, 0x17, 0xff, 0x73, 0x9b, 0x3d, 0xff, 0x42, 0x8f, 0x85, 0xff, 0x48, 0xd3, 0x2d, 0xff, 0x3d, 0x54, 0x81, 0xff, 0xce, 0x6b, 0xf8, 0xff, 0x96, 0x77, 0x97, 0xff, 0xed, 0x25, 0x34, 0xff, 0x9c, 0x67, 0xdc, 0xff, 0xcd, 0xfa, 0x53, 0xff, 0xb0, 0x85, 0x8d, 0xff, 0x2a, 0x3b, 0x58, 0xff, 0xd0, 0xb4, 0x96, 0xff, 0x9a, 0x30, 0x2b, 0xff, 0x12, 0x67, 0xaa, 0xff, 0x89, 0x53, 0xde, 0xff}, Stride:20, Rect:image.Rectangle{Min:image.Point{X:0, Y:0}, Max:image.Point{X:5, Y:5}}}

    got: &image.RGBA{Pix:[]uint8{0x56, 0x84, 0x7a, 0xff, 0xef, 0x60, 0x9b, 0xff, 0x10, 0x8a, 0x4d, 0xff, 0xfc, 0x76, 0x5e, 0xff, 0x65, 0x5a, 0xa5, 0xff, 0xfe, 0x97, 0x99, 0xff, 0xa7, 0x83, 0x32, 0xff, 0x92, 0xae, 0xb, 0xff, 0xd6, 0x7b, 0xde, 0xff, 0xab, 0x1, 0x17, 0xff, 0x73, 0x9b, 0x3d, 0xff, 0x42, 0x8f, 0x85, 0xff, 0x48, 0xd3, 0x2d, 0xff, 0x3d, 0x54, 0x81, 0xff, 0xce, 0x6b, 0xf8, 0xff, 0x96, 0x77, 0x97, 0xff, 0xed, 0x25, 0x34, 0xff, 0x9c, 0x67, 0xdc, 0xff, 0xcd, 0xfa, 0x53, 0xff, 0xb0, 0x85, 0x8d, 0xff, 0x2a, 0x3b, 0x58, 0xff, 0xd0, 0xb4, 0x96, 0xff, 0x9a, 0x30, 0x2b, 0xff, 0x12, 0x67, 0xaa, 0xff, 0x89, 0x53, 0xde, 0xff}, Stride:20, Rect:image.Rectangle{Min:image.Point{X:0, Y:0}, Max:image.Point{X:5, Y:5}}}[39m
```

**Note #1:** You can't (shouldn't) use [`reflect.DeepEqual()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual) to compare images, but it's clear from the output that after decoding the pixels are identical.

**Note #2:** You may pass [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) directly to [`png.Decode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/png/#Decode), no need to create another wrapper around it. It implements [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader), and its `Read()` method "serves" the data previously written into it:

```
outImage, err := png.Decode(out)
```

**Note #3:** When you use [`math/rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/), you should seed it with [`rand.Seed()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Seed) else you get the same pseudo-random sequence for each run (and not different, random data).

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
    inImage := image.NewNRGBA(image.Rectangle{upLeft, lowRight})
```

with `0` alpha, [Try it](https://play.golang.org/p/LvklbQKtdIU):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "image/png"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    width := 5
    height := 5
    upLeft := image.Point{0, 0}
    lowRight := image.Point{width, height}
    inImage := image.NewNRGBA(image.Rectangle{upLeft, lowRight})

    for x := 0; x < width; x++ {
        for y := 0; y < height; y++ {
            randomColor := color.RGBA{
                uint8(rand.Intn(255)),
                uint8(rand.Intn(255)),
                uint8(rand.Intn(255)),
                0}
            inImage.Set(x, y, randomColor)
        }
    }

    out := &bytes.Buffer{}
    err := png.Encode(out, inImage)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    outImage, err := png.Decode(out)
    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(inImage, outImage)) // true
}
```